# .Xauthority file is empty

Tags: ssh, x11, opensuse, xauth

I have been trying to `ssh -X` to my cluster running OpenSUSE 11.2. It used to work well for me. But now I get this message:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Failed to open the X11 display!
```

So I tried to check the ownership and permission of the `.Xauthority` file using

```
sudo ls -al .Xauthority
```

and I get to see that the file is empty with size 0:

```
-rw------- 1 <my-user-name> users 0 2014-07-31 10:03 .Xauthority
```

When I log in with `ssh -Xv`

I get the following when i try to open `xlock`

```
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from ::1 53267
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
debug1: channel 1: free: x11, nchannels 2
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: What does `echo $XAUTHORITY` give?

Comment: @celtschk That is not set. It gives me nothing.

Comment: Is `X11Forwarding` enabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the cluster? Also, is `UseLogin` set to `no`? (According to sshd_config(5), enabling `UseLogin` disables `X11Forwarding`)

Comment: @celtschk Yes. X11Forwarding is set to "yes" and UseLogin is set to "no"

Comment: Uppercase "Yes" or lowercase "yes"? It should be the latter.

Comment: Yes it's in lowercase. I corrected my typo in the comment

Comment: Is `xauth` in `/usr/bin/`? If not, is there an `XAuthLocation` in `sshd_config` giving its correct location? Also: Did you try using the `-v` option of `ssh` to get more information about what might go wrong?

Comment: Yes, xauth is present in /usr/bin/. And I have edited my question including -v option.

Comment: Can you start X11 applications locally from the terminal you're running ssh from?

Comment: Cluster is present at a remote location for which I need some authorized personnel. Will it make a difference? If so i can request them to try.

Comment: I mean the local window where you type the ssh command to log into the remote server.

Comment: Yes. It does. I am even able to ssh -X into other desktops and open X11 apps.

Answer (score 1):

If the filesystem containing your home directory on the remote server is 100% full or if disk quotas are in effect and you're over your quota, it might be possible to create a new zero-length file but not to write anything into it. This will stop `sshd` from being able to write a X11 session cookie into the `.Xauthority` file, causing the X11 forwarding to fail.

Check for these conditions, with commands `df -h .` and `quota`, before trying anything more elaborate. If necessary, clear some space, then log out and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some displays:

```
mcookie|sed -e 's/^/add :0 . /'|xauth -q

mcookie|sed -e 's/^/add :1 . /'|xauth -q
```

....................................